# Reset perspective values inner DIV

Tags: html, css, 3d, transform, perspective

I have some css 3D divs but im having some problems..
I want to rotate the outer div in perspective, but i don't want to rotate the inner div with it. How do I reset these styles to make the inner div flat again.

The HTML:

```
<section class="container" style="-webkit-perspective: 2000px; -webkit-perspective-origin-x: 0%; -webkit-perspective-origin-y: 0%;">
<div id="cube">
  <div class="bottom plutoring">
        <div class="planet pluto">
              <p> pluto </p>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 900px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
     -moz-perspective: 1200px;
       -o-perspective: 1200px;
          perspective: 1200px;
}

#cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.bottom {
     -webkit-transform: rotateX( 82deg ) rotateY( -5deg ) rotateZ( 197deg );
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think your problem may be with the preserve 3d. created a fiddle with your code but its not clear. http://jsfiddle.net/dKVCm/

Comment: updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dKVCm/1/ not a solution but somethign to play with at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 things:

- enable in the parent of the planet preserve3d
- transform the planet in the oposite way.

CSS

```
.bottom {
     -webkit-transform: rotateX( 82deg ) rotateY( -5deg ) rotateZ( 197deg );
    background:green;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.planet{
    background:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
     -webkit-transform:  rotateZ( -197deg ) rotateY( 5deg ) rotateX( -82deg ) ;
}
```

Note that the inverse transform is the original with the signs changed and the **order reversed**.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dKVCm/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the solution.

Comment: I was looking for a similar solution. Great solution! Except it breaks when you want to apply overflow-hidden to the .bottom

Answer (score 0):

my hunch is that in your code, the planet's ring needs to a child element of the planet, or a sibling of it. the ring should not be the parent of the planet if you don't want the ring's css transform to affect the planet.

have a look at this:

http://neography.com/experiment/circles/solarsystem/